# intellitest block vs 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, intellitest

Im doing intellitest code coverage for one of application which is huge and most likely completed.

Have run unit test for one of the api method which need to access db(Entity framework).

But test is not getting completed because of No connection string named \'ConStr\'could be found in the application config file.

Also the values in web config file is unreachable while intellitest run.
I'm not able to cover(71/185) the entire block because of this.
Should anything else needs to handled for accessing web config entries?

Thanks in advance

Ram

Comment: FYI: Im creating unit test for .net webapi application.

Comment: That wouldn't be considered a unit test by many people's standards;  because it is calling out to a database it would be more of an integration test;  the correct way to go about this is to use dependency injection (maybe the Fakes framework in VS if you have Enterprise edition) and let IntelliTest create data for your method.

Comment: The following example shows an example of an scenario;  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/08/14/intellitest-hands-on/  - the example shows the fake class as part of the application under test, but you might make a similar class to fake the entityframework behavior in your test class.  Hope this helps!